# Why can't I use ToListAsync() when using a parameter for the predicate in EF7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently implementing the [repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for my ASP.VNext application. I would like the methods to be asynchronous and filterable. So I have devised the following interface method:

`Task<TEntity> GetOneAsync(Func<TEntity,bool> predicate);`

and would like to implement it like this (with a private DbContext instance `ctx`):

```
public async Task<MyEntity> GetOneAsync(Func<MyEntity,bool> predicate) 
{
    // compiler error
    return await ctx.MyEntities.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

However I can only use `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` when hardcoding the predicate like this:

`return await ctx.MyEntites.Where(e => e.Id == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

When passing the predicate i only get the `FirstOrDefault()` without the async option, so in order to make my method asynchronous I have to write

```
public async Task<MyEntity> GetOneAsync(Func<MyEntity,bool> predicate) 
{
    //save to a local variable to prevent calling a disposed DbContext
    var entities = await Task.Run(() => ctx.Contracts.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault());
    return entities;
}
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Why is it not possible to access the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` method when passing a predicate?
2. Does my solution using `await Task.Run(synchronousMethod)` achieve the same behavior as a call to `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` would?

Comment: Regarding 1, can you post complete code and the compiler message. Likely a trivial issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirstOrDefaultAsync` is defined as an extension method for `IQueryable<T>`.

`ctx.MyEntities.Where(e => e.Id == 1)` returns `IQueryable<MyEntity>`.

`ctx.MyEntities.Where(predicate)` returns `IEnumerable<MyEntity>`, because you're calling the `Enumerable.Where` extension method, not the `Queryable.Where` one.

To make it work, change `predicate` from `Func<MyEntity, bool>` to `Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>`. This means `predicate` is no longer just a function that gives the result you want, but a description of that function, that Entity Framework can then translate to SQL.

And no, using `Func<MyEntity, bool>` within a task would not have the same behaviour. That would load rows from the db server without any filtering, and evaluate each and every one at the db client until a match is found. That would add a lot of overhead.